# HtmlUnit, how to get button without a name attribute

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" onclick="ASPxLoadingPanel1.Show();">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-paste"></i></span>
                            <span class="bold">Search</span>
                        </button>
```

So I want to get this Button from a html page.

```
button = a.getInputByName("btnLogin");
```

this is not the way. Can someone help me and tell me how to fetch this button through HtmlUnit.

Comment: Try using xpath to get the button.

Comment: @linkstatic So did this work? You haven't provided any feedback

Answer (score 3):

Try to get by the tag name, and then specify the index in the list:

```
HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) page.getElementsByTagName("button").get(0);
```

// It didn't work to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath should be the best approach. The thing is that you'll have to find the most appropriate XPath yourself.

Once you have that XPath criteria the HtmlUnit code is simple:

```
HtmlButton button = page.getFirstByXPath("//button[@type='submit' and span[text()=='Search']]");
button.click();
```

I'm not sure if the XPath string I suggested would do the trick but it should be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

An example to get the button using xpath.

**Sample Code**

```
public void xpath() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");

    //get list of all divs
    final List<?> divs = page.getByXPath("//div");

    //get div which has a 'name' attribute of 'John'
    final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@name='John']/button").get(0);

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```